# Trouble sending cookie / session from Express backend to React frontend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, redis

I'm having trouble retrieving a session / cookie from an `express` backend to a `react` frontend.

Front end:

```
async function submitData() {
    await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8082/api/login', {
        credentials: 'include',
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }); // backend logs req.session.userId as intended (req.session.userId = something)

    await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8082/api/verify', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            withCredentials: true
    }); // backend logs req.session.userId = undefined
};
```

Backend:
`authServer.ts`:

```
import cors from 'cors';
import session from 'express-session';
import redis from 'redis';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

const redisClient = redis.createClient();
const redisStore = connectRedis(session);
import authRoute from './routes/authRoute';

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
}));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'Session secret',
    store: new redisStore({
        client: redisClient,
        ttl: 24 * 60 * 60
    }),
    name: 'session',
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
    },
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
}));
app.use('/api', authRoute);
```

`authRoute.ts`:

```
route.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    req.session.userId = 'something';
    console.log('Login request session: ' + req.session.userId);
    res.json('you are now logged in');
});

route.post('/verify', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.userId);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

When login route is called, it normally sets and logs the req.session.userId like it is supposed to. However, when I call the verify route after calling the login route from the frontend, it logs that req.session.userId is undefined. How can I fix this?

What I've tried:

- Using both axios and fetch in case it's an axios problem
- Running the website from google, firefox, bing and internet explorer to make sure that it's not a browser issue
- Messing with CORS configuration in the backend
- Reading other similar posts from this website searching for a solution for similar problems

Feel free to ask any questions for this question as the code is provided in a minimalistic form.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a temporary fix by using `fetch` instead of `axios`. I added the following code on the frontend.

```
await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8082/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
});

await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8082/api/verify', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
});
```

Please comment on this post if you find a solution when using axios.